# Join two subquery in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I am having problem in joint two subqueries in MySQL, e.g.

```
(select * from table1 where id = 1 group by f1) a1 
join 
(select * from table2 where id = 2 group by f2) a2 ON  a1.f3 = a2.f3;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'join (select * from table1 where id = 2)' at line 1

Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: Sorry for my simplified example, I have updated the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check out some examples**

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2;

SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;

SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;

SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 USING (id);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I've been googling for a few days to no avail until I hit this question.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as written.  This question matches the google search for joining two subqueries. Consequently @a_horse_with_no_name's answer actually fits better.